# LINQ to SQL from DataTable to database join

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am very new to linq to SQL. So need some help.

I have some data in the datatable. I would like to join that with another SQL server DataBase table and get results.

For example, I have an array of Products which contains fields like PartNumber, Quantity etc. I want to join that array (PartNumber) with the datatable table (Products) having field ID matching with array of Products.PartNumber. Is it possible?

Later I want to update database with some filters based on the results of the join. For example, if Quantity in the array is less than 10, then update another database table. and if greater than zero, then update another.

Can we do this via Linq to SQL?

thanks
Sameers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible...however it is problematic joining local data objects to database table.  I posted a similar question a while ago which might help.

[LinqToSQL joining local list to table - confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181948/linqtosql-joining-local-list-to-table-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This link gives you detail about Linq to SQL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

you can try this.

```
from p in dataContext.Product
join q in dataContext.Quantity on p.P_ID equals q.P_ID
where ... you condition goes here
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but seems I am getting error "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context"

Comment: I included both classes into same Datacontext and above error disappeared. But came with new error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator." Using Query 'Dim result = From p In dc.ProductWarehouses Join q In list On p.ProductID Equals q.DAndHItemNumber Where q.QtyAvailAllBranches > 0'  Note the list contains large number of rows added manually, its generic list.